# can we say "to wrestle/throw someone over"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idioms

> "[To push/knock someone over](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/push-over?q=push%20over)" means "​to make somebody/something fall
>   to the ground by pushing/hitting them"
>
> Sam pushed me over in the playground.

Similarly, can we say "**to wrestle/throw someone over**"?

I asked this questions because I saw 2 children wrestling and one fell down onto the ground (like a judo technique). Using "**push / knock**" is not suitable in this case.

Comment: Did you try using it? Were you understood?  Have you done any other research like a google search for the phrase?

Comment: In theory, yes, but whether it sounds natural or not will depend a lot on context.  If you have any more specifics about how you were wanting to use it and what you're trying to say, people might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: to ***wrestle over***, like ***punch over***, wouldn't occur very often - [those verbs would usually occur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrestled+him+over%2Cwrestled+him+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrestled%20him%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrestled%20him%20down%3B%2Cc0) as ***wrestle down*** (and perhaps ***punch down***).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Sam pushed me over in the playground.

You were standing up and he pushed you over.

- Sam **wrestled me to the ground** in the playground.

You were attacked by Sam and the two of your wrestled and you fell to the ground.

- Sam **threw me to the ground** in the playground.

That is like pushed only more active. You were fighting and he "threw you" to the ground.

**throw over** does not work:

Sam threw the ball over my head.

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase you want is "throw down" not "throw over." To "throw over" suggests throwing the person over something, like over a balcony railing. "Throw down" means to throw something to the ground or the floor, or (if you are talking about an object like a glove or cards), onto a table or other surface. Similarly, if you are wrestling someone to the floor, you would probably say "wrestle down" unless there is something in the way and you are wrestling over that.